# Lines overlapping labels

Tags: labels, flowcharts

I have an issue where data point lines are overlapping labels. You can see this below:

[image]

With multiple lines passing over labels it currently gets quite messy.

In terms of user behaviour, would the best thing be, to move the label infront automatically if a line goes over it?

Comment: Yes. But also make sure that the user knows which line the text represents.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted some other opinions of what we could do.